# Laravel 5.1 - append Blade from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

i would like append blade in my ajax list of comments:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tablaDatos = $("#comentos");
    var route = "http://localhost:8000/commentList";

    $.get(route, function(res){

        $(res).each(function(key,value){
            tablaDatos.append("<div class='comment'><a class='comment-avatar' href='"+value.user_id+"'><img class='avatar-image-comments' src='{{url($comment->user->profile)}}' width='60' alt=''></a><div class='comment-body'><strong>"+value.user_id+"</strong><h7 class='comment-date'>  -  commentato il "+value.created_at+"</h7><p class='comment-text'>"+value.content+"</p>@if(Auth::check())@if(Auth::user()->id == $comment->user_id || Auth::user()->usertype == 3 )<div class='reply'><div class='inline'><button type='button' value='{{$comment->id}}' class='btn btn-circle btn-dark btn-xs btn-outline' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'><span>editare</span></button></div><div class='inline'>{!!Form::open(['route'=>['comment.destroy',$comment->id]])!!}<input type='hidden' name='_method' value='DELETE'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-circle btn-dark btn-xs btn-outline'><span>Elimina</span></button>{!!Form::close()!!}</div></div>@endif@endif</div></div>")

        });
    });

});
```

I need append blade functions for user logged and not. But it doesnt work, i attached a photo with the result:

[image]

Comment: Are you actually in a .blade.php file? Because your Blade statements aren't getting parsed.

Comment: @JoelHinz  i have  comment.js for my script js, and article.blade.php for html list of comments

Comment: Well, there you have it, then. You can't run php in javascript files.

Comment: @MikeBarwick yes but i would like append data html with blade how can i do it?

Comment: @Jonathan yes maybe you  have reason, but i tryed to fix like other answer and did not work well

Comment: @Diego182 so why do you need to have comments as an array in javascript exactly? Is there any reason or just because "why not"?

Comment: @Diego182 please come back to this question - its better if we wrap it up in some way ;)

Answer (score 4):

Writing blade syntax to the loaded HTML document will never give you the results you would like. Here's what you can do instead.

#### Create a template for the comments.

**resources/views/comments-template.blade.php**

```
<div class='comment'>
    <a class='comment-avatar' href='{{ $comment->user->id }}'>
        <img class='avatar-image-comments' src='{{ url($comment->user->profile) }}' width='60' alt=''>
    </a>

    <div class='comment-body'>
        <strong>{{ $comment->user->id }}</strong>
        <h7 class='comment-date'>  -  commentato il {{ $comment->created_at }}</h7>
        <p class='comment-text'>{{ $comment->content }}</p>

        @if(Auth::check())
            @if(Auth::user()->id == $comment->user->id || Auth::user()->usertype == 3 )
                <div class='reply'>
                    <div class='inline'>
                        <button type='button' value='{{ $comment->id }}' class='btn btn-circle btn-dark btn-xs btn-outline' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
                            <span>editare</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class='inline'>{!! Form::open(['route'=>['comment.destroy',$comment->id]]) !!}
                        <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='DELETE'>
                        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-circle btn-dark btn-xs btn-outline'>
                            <span>Elimina</span>
                        </button>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

#### In your controller, instead of returning the JSON object just return a JSON array of the rendered blade HTML.

**app/Http/Controllers/CommentController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Comment;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function commentList()
    {
        // store the comments list
        $list = [];

        // retrieve comments
        $comments = Comment::all();

        // render each comment and store it
        foreach ($comments as $comment) {
            $html = view('comments-template')
                ->with('comment', $comment)
                ->render();

            $list[] = $html;
        }

        // return a JSON array of the comments list
        return response()->json($list);
    }
}
```

#### AJAX call

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tablaDatos = $("#comentos");
    var route = "http://localhost:8000/commentList";

    $.get(route, function(res){

        $(res).each(function(key,value){
            tablaDatos.append(value);

        });
    });

});
```

Comment: @Diego182 If this works for you please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use like this. The best way would be, separate the template in a blade.php file. Then using jQuery load the data and push them to the template using DOM manipulation.

I would have put the html codes in blade template:

```
<div class='comment'>
<a class='comment-avatar' id="a_link" href=''>
<img class='avatar-image-comments' src='{{url($comment->user->profile)}}' width='60' alt=''>
</a>
<div class='comment-body'>
<strong>"+value.user_id+"</strong>
<h7 class='comment-date'>  -  commentato il "+value.created_at+"</h7>
<p class='comment-text'>"+value.content+</p>

@if(Auth::check())@if(Auth::user()->id == $comment->user_id || Auth::user()->usertype == 3 )
<div class='reply'><div class='inline'><button type='button' value='{{$comment->id}}' class='btn btn-circle btn-dark btn-xs btn-outline' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
<span>editare</span></button></div><div class='inline'>{!!Form::open(['route'=>['comment.destroy',$comment->id]])!!}<input type='hidden' name='_method' value='DELETE'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-circle btn-dark btn-xs btn-outline'><span>Elimina</span></button>{!!Form::close()!!}</div></div>@endif@endif</div></div>
```

And use jQuery to append value to the DOM

```
$(res).each(function(key,value){
    $('#a_link').attr('href', value.id);
});
```

Include the .blade.php template within your current view template.

Comment: Ah.. ok, so if i create "comment2.blade.php" with my blade code:  "if(Auth::user()->id...etc.."  how can i append a file reference ?

Answer (score 1):

> All Blade views are compiled into plain PHP code and cached until they
> are modified [#Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#introduction)

You need to save the javascript as blade file, `myjavascript.blade.php` to be compiled to php. Then use **@include** directive to include that script file.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do too many things mangled together. Time to re-evaluate?

You haven't given any reason as to why you need to load via jQuery's `$.get()`.

But you certainly can't have PHP inside the javascript.

Why not re-design whatever happens at `/commentList` so that its controller has access to your `$comments`, and have that controller's action `return view('commentlist');` instead?

Then your comments page template is something like:

```
@forelse($comments as $comment)
    <div class='comment'>
        <a class='comment-avatar' href='{{ $comment->user->id }}'>
            <img class='avatar-image-comments' src='{{ url($comment->user->profile) }}' width='60' alt=''>
        </a>
        <div class='comment-body'>
            <strong>{{ $comment->user->id }}</strong>
            <h7 class='comment-date'>  -  commentato il {{ $comment->created_at }}</h7>
            <p class='comment-text'>{{ $comment->content }}</p>
            @if(Auth::check())
              @if(Auth::user()->id == $comment->user_id || Auth::user()->usertype == 3)
                  <div class='reply'>
                    <div class='inline'>
                        <button type='button' value='{{ $comment->id }}' class='btn btn-circle btn-dark btn-xs btn-outline' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
                            <span>editare</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class='inline'>
                        {!! Form::open(['route'=>['comment.destroy', $comment->id]]) !!}
                            <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='DELETE'>
                            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-circle btn-dark btn-xs btn-outline'>
                                <span>Elimina</span>
                            </button>
                        {!!Form::close()!!}
                    </div>
                  </div>
              @endif
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
@empty
    There are no comments
@endforelse
```

And your get is something like:

```
$.get(route, function (data) {
    tablaDatos.append(data);
});
```

But really, I don't understand your reasoning for doing this. You need to have explained this aspect of your question as well as it seems like you're over-engineering your problem.

But seriously, if you are going to have some epic one-line string like you have had in your `append()`, it should be ringing alarm bells that something isn't quite right.